# Linux core dump vs heap dump?

Tags: java, linux, memory-management, coredump, memory-dump

I have this file on Linux box. To me it looks like core dump and different from heap dump. Right?

```
8dbe79c2f000-8dbe79c34000 r--s 005f8000 fd:01 30800604                 /path../charsets.jar
8dbe79c34000-8dbe79c35000 r--s 00007000 fd:01 30800604                 /path../sunec.jar
8dbe79c35000-8dbe79c3a000 rw-p 00063000 fd:01 30800604                 /path../jsse.jar
```

...............

If it's core dump what does it represent? I understand 8dbe79c2f000-8dbe79c34000 should be memory space. But what does this info represent?

1. 30800604
2. /path../charsets.jar
3. fd:01

Comment: Where did come from? You see, if it was generated by a failing JVM, it might still be a java heap dump.

Comment: It has been provided as memory dump file from production environment. So i am not sure what it is actually. But anyways it does not contain object details like what are the objects lying in memory that point of time,their size, no of objects which are expected as heap dump? so it sdoes not look like heap dump to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `file` command. More details at `man 1 file`
It shows something like below on system for a core dump

```
➜  ~  file core.28983
core.28983: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from './a.out'
➜  ~
```

whereas `jar` files are not usually core files, they are java archive. Output of `file` command on jar looks like following on my system

```
file /usr/share/texmf/scripts/ppower4/pp4p.jar
/usr/share/texmf/scripts/ppower4/pp4p.jar: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

Comment: ELF 64-bit LSB **core file** x86-64

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this i did not get ?

Comment: `file` command will tell you type of file. In the above example it says it is ELF 64-bit, core file.